Drupal Commerce: Set number of decimals on Price after mathematical operations
I have a commerce_price field on an entity. This field is populated dynamically on entity pre-save. Example:
$total = new Price('100', 'USD');
$deposit_percentage = '12.125';
$deposit = $total->multiply($deposit_percentage)->divide('100');
// Deposit is 12.125.
$entity->set('field_deposit', $deposit);

The problem is that even though $total is set to USD (two decimals), after performing the mathematical operation, the $deposit, though still in USD, is 3 decimals. The resultant 3-decimal Price is then stored in the entity field, and on display, shows three decimals, even though the field is storing a price in 'USD'.
So, I am wondering how to handle this:

Is there a method of trimming the $deposit Price to 2-decimals before storing on the entity? Or maybe
Is there a way to choose the field formatter to show 2-decimals?


The solution is to use the rounder service to round the final number to the correct number of decimals:
$total = new Price('100', 'USD');
$deposit_percentage = '12.125';
$deposit = $total->multiply($deposit_percentage)->divide('100');
$rounder_service = \Drupal::service('commerce_price.rounder');
$entity->set('field_deposit', $rounder_service->round($deposit));

